# How to include the content of one PHP file in another master file?

Tags: php, include

```
//Grab and assign List ID from confirmation URL 
$L = $_GET["L"]; 

//Set Redirects based on List ID  
if($L == "1") { 
header("Location: http://stat.domain.com/");
exit();
}
```

This is the content of a redirection rule that I have created, but I am thinking of putting these in a separate file instead of the master file MASTER.php. I was reading online and there are different ways of reading the content off a separate file, of which are functions like include() include_once(). However, after reading through some information online, i am still not very sure what i should do to include the above content in the master file.

Any efficient way of doing this?

Comment: yes you could just `include();` it. Take care of the `headers already sent` warnings.

Comment: If this must be executed in MASTER.php, then `include 'thisfile.php';`  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546160/include-include-once-require-or-require-once for the differences.

Answer (score 1):

You only want to include that file once in a certain place. Perhaps add an include to `redirects.php` from `master.php`:

```
require_once 'redirects.php';
```

You could also use `include_once`, but that will not halt the script if the file cannot be found and will fail silently - which is usually much worse than explicitly.

Comment: Hi, so i should insert the following code to my master.php:

require_once "redirects.php"; 

is that right?

Comment: Yes, up the top before any other code is executed to ensure nothing is written to output beforehand.

Comment: Must it be all the way at the top or could I insert it in the same line where the previous codes were located?

Comment: Basically you can't write anything before the `header` call. If you do so accidentally the redirect will fail, and you may not be aware of it until users experience it or you test it, so it's a good idea to put it somewhere at the top or ensure there won't be output when it's called.