# How can i call a php variable from a seperate file into a HTML file

Tags: javascript, php, json

Here is the actual file which i want to seperate the javascript from.
How do i tell the javascript where to look for the php file, at the moment i am only able to execute the javascript from within the php file..

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
require_once("DbConnect.php");

$sql = "SELECT `artist`, `title`, `label`, `albumyear`, `date_played`, `duration`,
`picture` FROM historylist  ORDER BY `date_played` DESC LIMIT 5 ";

$result = $db->query($sql);

$lastplayed = array();
$i = 1;
while ($row=$result->fetch_object()) {
$lastplayed[$i]['artist'] = $row->artist;
$lastplayed[$i]['title'] = $row->title;
$lastplayed[$i]['label'] = $row->label;
$lastplayed[$i]['albumyear'] = $row->albumyear;
$lastplayed[$i]['date_played'] = $row->date_played;
$lastplayed[$i]['duration'] = $row->duration;
$lastplayed[$i]['picture'] = $row->picture;
$i++;
}

$starttime = strtotime($lastplayed[1]['date_played']);
$curtime = time();
$timeleft = $starttime+round($lastplayed[1]['duration']/1000)-$curtime;
$secsremain = (round($lastplayed[1]['duration'] / 1000)-($curtime-$starttime));


$lastplayedjson = json_encode( $lastplayed );
?>
```

**i want this part to be in a separate file**

```
<script type="text/javascript">


var lastplayedjson = <?php echo $lastplayedjson ?>;


alert( lastplayedjson[1].title );
alert( lastplayedjson[2].title );
alert( lastplayedjson[3].title );
alert( lastplayedjson[4].title );
</script>
```

Comment: (1) At what moments do you need to check the variables? (2) When is $lastplayed updated?

Answer (score 0):

You could [include](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) the first php file (we'll call it fileA.php) which would allow fileB.php to access all of it's variables

**File A**

```
<?php 
$cats = 'topkek';
```

**File B**

```
<?php
include('/path/to/fileA.php');
echo $cats;
```

Should output

```
topkek
```

---

You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546160/include-include-once-require-or-require-once) for the differences on `include`, `require`, `include_once` and `require_once`

Answer (score 0):

in your php:

```
include_once('templates/template-name.php');
```