# how can I use of a php variable into a .css file

Tags: php, html, css

I have a css file named `test.css` and I want to use into it of `$var`.`$var` is at `test.php`. `test.css` is attached in `test.php`. My structure is something like this:

```
//test.php

<html>
<head>
<?php $var = 'anything';?>
<link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

and this is test.css:

```
// test.css

.<?php echo $var> { // css property }
```

Currently `test.css` does not work. In fact, I want to knoe how can I use of a php variable as a class name into a css file ?

Comment: as written, impossible. css is not executed as a php script, so any php code in the css will go out to the client and be considered a css syntax error. you CAN make it execute as php on the server, but then it will execute completely SEPARATELY from the script that's producing the `<link>` tag, and `$var` will be undefined in the css.

Comment: I also add another solution for you. If you think that is the answer, please change your decision for new comers.

Comment: @MarcB when I put a `.css` file in head, It will be cache in user browser. but what happens when I write my css property on `head` between `<style>` and `</style>` ? what happens  with each request ? is it optimized ?

Comment: then you're wasting a bit of bandwidth by sending the same css snippet on every one of your pages. it'd get cached as part of the page, but since it's duplicated on ALL pages, it'd be cached mutiple times.

Comment: @MarcB look, for preventing of parsing my data in html page, I use dynamic class name for my elements, and I create these names with php, now in your opinion, is it bad a idea ?

Comment: rather pointless, since you don't NEED classes to parse html. they make it easier, but you can still yank apart html purely by the structure. `3rd table, 4th row, 3rd cell, 2nd paragraph`, works just as well as `$('.thing_you_want')`.

Comment: @MarcB I thought about that already. I will `echo` html tags as random between my main tags. `<div>for preventing parser</div><div> main data </div>`. there is just sometime the first `<div>`.

Comment: @MarcB can I chat with you [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82340/room-for-stack-and-marc-b) a little ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually you can.

### 1st **Solution**

Instead of using the .css file extension, use .php

**Set up variables**

```
<?php

   header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8"); //look carefully to this line

   $brandColor = "#990000";
   $linkColor  = "#555555";
?>
```

**Use variables**

```
#header {
   background: url("<?php echo $CDNURL; ?>/images/header-bg.png") no-repeat;
}
a {
  color: <?php echo $linkColor; ?>;
}

...

ul#main-nav li a {
  color: <?php echo $linkColor; ?>;
}
```

---

### 2nd and short solution

Create a file and name it like style.php, then in your style.php set your styles in  tags like below

**style.php**

```
<style>
.blabla{
   ....
}

#heeeHoo{
   ...
}
</style>
```

then include style.php to your file (test.php) like

```
<html>
<head>
    <?php include 'style.php'; ?>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

That is the correct answer. Think like inline css but that is actually in external file

Comment: your Idea is great ! +1 for you.

Comment: `include` or  `require` or `include_once` or `require_once` ? which one is more optimized ?

Comment: Please see this answer for your new question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3546316/1848929

Comment: then `require_once()` is the best in this case.

Comment: You should `mod_rewrite` `style.css` to `style.php` though imho

Comment: If I use `require_once();` in head, it will be run before html tags ?

Comment: Just use `<link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />` and in your `.htaccess` file you can `rewrite` `style.css` to `style.php`. This way the browser can take advantage of caching the resource.

Comment: no. require_once is kind of strong include. if it fails, page stop working but if you use include page continues working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<style>` in the PHP file.

```
//test.php

<html>
<head>
<?php $var = 'anything';?>
</head>
<body>
<style>
<?php echo $var; ?>
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

The style can also be put in the `<head>`.

Comment: Then you'd have to configure your server to treat your `css` files as PHP files.

Comment: @mittmemo is it possible ?! and is it hard ?

Comment: @rjdown what ? what is your mean of *Most browsers don't understand scoped* , using  `<style>` is a bad idea ?

Comment: Parsing CSS as PHP is Ill-advised. Just use a PHP file in your link. And @stack I was referring to the unedited answer http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/31214136/1 - but yes, using inline styles is generally a bad idea, especially half-way through the document.

Comment: @stack I had included the "scoped" attribute in my original answer and edited it out. rjdown saw that before it was edited out.